# htaccess mod_rewrite conundrum

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, so I have this .htaccess file that contains this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php?p=%{REQUEST_URI}&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Problem is, that in apache 2.2.22, the `p` and the other query objects don't come through,
but it works great in apache 2.4.2 .

So basically in apache 2.2.22 it just forwards everything to index.php, but it doesn't have any `get` objects.

Any help, thanks.

**Update**

Ok so I changed the line

`RewriteRule . /index.php?p=%{REQUEST_URI}&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

to

`RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]` 
And now on apache 2.2.22 the `p` GET doesn't go through, but any specific queries I add go through.

So If I do

`http://localhost/index/fun/buns/funds?man=woman`

on 2.4.2 I get

```
array (size=2)
  'p' => string 'index/fun/buns/funds' (length=20)
  'man' => string 'woman' (length=5)
```

and on 2.2.22 I get

```
array(1) {
  ["man"]=>
  string(5) "woman"
}
```

**To be clear** What's happening on 2.4.2 is what I want, and 2.2.22 isn't cooperating.

**Another Update** Ok so it seems like what is happening is that when I do /index/whatever, it auto assumes index.php, and ignores that, it auto adds the .php to it, when I don't want it to. Any ideas on how to stop that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needed to put add `-MultiViews` to the httpd.conf file.